# PowerShell ISE Using Foreach for XML Array

Tags: xml, powershell

**Hello i'm new for XML , just want to know is it possible to loop array and get real value of each one**

```
 $authFullName = "authClientId"
 $portalURLName = "portalBaseUrl"
 $portalPathName = "portalBasePath"
 $serviceUrlName = "serviceBaseUrl"
 $servicePathName = "serviceBasePath"
```

**This is my Array:**

```
$attributeArray = @('$authFullName','$portalURLName','$portalPathName', '$serviceUrlName', '$servicePathName')
```

**This is my suggested array loop:**

```
foreach ($attribute in $attributeArray)
{
    Write-Host 'Works.. And here you are ' $attribute
}
```

**Result::**

```
p $authFullName
p $portalURLName
p $portalPathName
p $serviceUrlName
p $servicePathName
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, found a solution
just instead of '**

```
$attributeArray = @('$authFullName','$portalURLName','$portalPathName', '$serviceUrlName', '$servicePathName')
```

**use " , when filling an array**

```
$attributeArray = @("$authFullName","$portalURLName","$portalPathName", "$serviceUrlName", "$servicePathName")
```

**now result is ::**

```
p authClientId
p portalBaseUrl
p portalBasePath
p serviceBaseUrl
p serviceBasePath
```

Comment: This is _not_ related to array construction - you want to use `"` **when you want variable references in string literals expanded.** You could have done `$attributeArray = $authFullName,$portalURLName,$portalPathName,$serviceUrlName,$servicePathName`

Comment: Could you please say, how to trim this $ from the  first result using ' ?

Comment: or any other variants.. i mean what if i just want array variable name , not value ..

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you want to print `authFullName`, why not just store the string `"authFullName"` in the array? And what does any of this have to do with XML?

Comment: i want to create a tool , that will work after pipeline DevOps call ..   After it calling this parameters filling automatically ... authFullName - > this is a variable of the element in the  XML .... whats about "authFullName " this is the parameter that will change authFullName  element , name=".." field

Comment: with the help of a loop, I will know which value from XML get Ex: <authFullName name="'authFullName'"

Comment: Please add all those details (and perhaps a sample XML file) [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66676944/edit) if you want any qualified help - no one can read your mind over the internet :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66678785/powershell-edit-xml-element-attribute-value